# iOS app crashed on 15.2.1 on endUpdates on UITableView from cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting this crash on crashlytics for iOS 15.2.1.

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (17) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Table view: <UITableView: 0x14bc56000; frame = (0 0; 414 600); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280a7bed0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x281340000>; contentOffset: {0, 273.66666666666669}; contentSize: {414, 873.66668128967285}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <AppName.MyViewController: 0x14b968a00>>

```
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess 5 UIKitCore
-[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] 6 AppName <compiler-generated> FormTextFieldCell.textViewDidEndEditing(_:) 7 AppName <compiler-generated> @objc FormTextFieldCell.textViewDidEndEditing(_:) 8 UIKitCore
-[UITextView _notifyDidEndEditing] 10 UIKitCore
-[UITableView reloadData] 11 AppName UITableView+Extensions.swift - Line 26 partial apply for closure #1 in UITableView.reloadViewData() + 26 12 AppName <compiler-generated> thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () 13 libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_call_block_and_release 21 UIKitCore UIApplicationMain 22 AppName AppDelegate.swift - Line 23 main + 23
```

Crash happened on update tableview from cell

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate{
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please add more code, there is not enough context to solve this issue. Where is the code that is in your sample called from? When is it called?

Comment: You add or delete data from tableView (swipe or other action ) and then reload your table view before having updated your data source.

Comment: We are not adding or deleting data from tableview. Our sample code is called from UITableViewCell 
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
}

Comment: @PtitXav Any update?

Comment: The text view is in the cell. And at some point you reload data which cause text view notify end. You may come to an inconstancy at some point as you are reloading tableview and cell is locked by text view being used for calling tableView update. I think you have a kind of circular dependency on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PtitXav You are right. I got this issue when textfield editing is in progress and tableview reload is called. Thanks!